# Grails cannot access H2 tables

Tags: grails

I am having issues connecting to the H2 database while my application is running. I currently have grails.dbconsole.enabled set to true in the config file, but whenever I try to access the database through

```
https://localhost:8080/app-name/dbconsole
```

I do not have access. I currently have the spring-security plugin installed and each time I try to access this page it asks me to login through the security protocol, not through the H2 console. When I attempt to login using through spring-security I am still not able to view the table. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't made any changes to DataSource.groovy you should find the url to the db there, also username 'sa' password blank - as seen in the DataSource.groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your `Config.groovy` allow access to the `dbconsole` URL

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
  '/dbconsole*':['permitAll']
]
```

You can also disable spring security for development temporarily

```
environments {
   development {
      grails.plugins.springsecurity.active = false
   } 
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same issue when using the first method and when I tried doing the second method I end up with the error of it not being able to encode passwords.

Comment: The error that I am getting is 'ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object
Message: Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object' which is in grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService

Comment: @Jakel309 do you have rules under `grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap` other than the one I suggested? Maybe another rule is overriding this one.

Comment: That is the only rule that I have under that.

Comment: I have now figured out that I needed to add the first solution of adding the permit all line to the Spring Security static rules, because placing it separate did not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I added in my Config.groovy to access the dbconsole with spring security installed.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/':                    ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':           ['permitAll'],
    '/partials/**':         ['permitAll'],
    '/dbconsole*/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**':                  ['isAuthenticated()']
```

]